# Change log level for UserManager

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager` logs invalid passwords as log level `Warning`.
How can I downgrade that to info? It's getting a bit noisy in the logs...

Comment: You can configure it in the appsettings file have a look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging

Comment: Yeah just found that. The identity source code does not have any mechanisms to adjust levels

Comment: also if you downgrade it to info every thing above info eg info, warning ,error and critical will be logged. If you want less logging you need to set it to a higher level https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Increased it to Error

Comment: Could you please tell me which codes you have used which logs the invalid passwords? As far as I know, the identity will use `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` to check the password. And it will just add the ` ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");`.

Comment: @BrandoZhang `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do that is to adjust [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging) and filter the logs afterwards. I cannot recommend overriding .net security code

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider creating the custom a custom SignInManager and modify the codes which is related with logs.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
using AspNetCoreNormalIssue.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AspNetCoreNormalIssue
{
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<IdentityUser>
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public ApplicationSignInManager(
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser> claimsFactory,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<SignInManager<IdentityUser>> logger,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
            IUserConfirmation<IdentityUser> confirmation
            )
            : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes, confirmation)
        {
            _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
             Logger = logger;
        }
        public override async Task<SignInResult> CheckPasswordSignInAsync(IdentityUser user, string password, bool lockoutOnFailure)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            }

            var error = await PreSignInCheck(user);
            if (error != null)
            {
                return error;
            }

            if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
            {
                var alwaysLockout = AppContext.TryGetSwitch("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.CheckPasswordSignInAlwaysResetLockoutOnSuccess", out var enabled) && enabled;
                // Only reset the lockout when not in quirks mode if either TFA is not enabled or the client is remembered for TFA.
                if (alwaysLockout || !await IsTfaEnabled(user) || await IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user))
                {
                    await ResetLockout(user);
                }

                return SignInResult.Success;
            }

            //Modify to log error or else based on your requirement.
            Logger.LogError("InvalidPassword", "User failed to provide the correct password.");

            if (UserManager.SupportsUserLockout && lockoutOnFailure)
            {
                // If lockout is requested, increment access failed count which might lock out the user
                await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
                if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
                {
                    return await LockedOut(user);
                }
            }
            return SignInResult.Failed;
        }

        private async Task<bool> IsTfaEnabled(IdentityUser user)
    => UserManager.SupportsUserTwoFactor &&
    await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user) &&
    (await UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(user)).Count > 0;




    }
}
```

Then you could modify the startup.cs's ConfigureServices to use the custom SignInManager `.AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()`.

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

Comment: Na, sorry, can't accept that as an answer. I'm not advocating anyone to override security code. Just playing with log levels for now

Comment: As far as I know, the SignInManager source class is public and the CheckPasswordSignInAsync method is virtual that means you could override these codes and what I have done is just modify one line Logger.LogError. If you don't want to use this way, we couldn't modify the logger type by using other ways.